# Why is the output of the “*” command boot?

Tags: bash, command-line, command

I used the `*` command and I seen this error:

```
bash: boot: command not found
```

Why did this error occur?

Comment: `*` is not a command, it's a glob/wildcard. It matches everything in the current directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first word that you type on the command line will be interpreted by your shell as the name of a command.

The shell will expand the `*` filename globbing character to all visible names in the current directory. The names will be sorted in lexicographical order.

You are in a directory in which the name `boot` is the name that sorts first.  This means that typing just `*` *in that particular directory* will be the same as trying to run a command called `boot` with all other names from that directory as command line arguments.

On your system, there is no command called `boot` in your current `$PATH`, so the shell complains that it can't find it.

That's what happens.

Example on my system (running the `zsh` shell rather than `bash`, but it work the same in this respect):

```
% cd /
% ls
altroot    bsd        bsd.sp     home       sbin       usr
bin        bsd.booted dev        mnt        sys        var
boot       bsd.rd     etc        root       tmp
% *
zsh: command not found: altroot
```

When I use just `*`, the shell tries to run a command called `altroot`, because the name `altroot` (which happens to be the name of a directory) sorts first in the expansion of the `*` filename globbing pattern in the directory I was in.

Selecting commands to run by means of filename globbing patterns is error prone and dangerous, and therefore best avoided.

---

As a somewhat related anecdote, I *believe* I've seen users create a file called `-i` in directories with important files. So they may have something like

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 myself  wheel  0 Apr 16 18:49 -i
-rw-r--r--  1 myself  wheel  0 Apr 16 18:49 important-file-1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 myself  wheel  0 Apr 16 18:49 important-file-2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 myself  wheel  0 Apr 16 18:49 important-file-3.txt
```

Notice how `-i` sorts first?  This means that when they do `rm -rf *` (by mistake) in this directory, this happens:

```
$ rm -rf *
remove important-file-1.txt? n
remove important-file-2.txt? n
remove important-file-3.txt? n
```

That is, the `-i` name is inserted as an option to `rm -rf`, which makes `rm` ask for confirmation before removing any files. They then get a chance to abort the operation.

This is a fun little trick, but not at all the right solution to the issue of accidentally deleting files.  The correct solution to *that* issue is to make regular backups.